# Opencart enabling SEO url leads to 404 error

Tags: php, opencart, shopping-cart

I'm using opencart version 1.5.5.1 for our website.

When I enable seo in admin section the urls lead to 404.
My site url is https://www.domain.com/dev/. 
The .htaccess file content is as follows:

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /dev/
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

I know this topic is already posted but the solutions provided didn't work for me.

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did You rename the `.htaccess.txt` file to **`.htaccess`** file (*no .txt extension*)???

Comment: It is .htaccess and not .htaccess.txt.

Comment: Is your server running Apache?

Comment: Hi..@SankarV...did u used any module for this...SEO?

Comment: Hi @SankarV...My suggestion for SEO extension ....
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=9858(Its free of cost)..

Answer (score 5):

Check this list for search some errors:

1. Renamed .htaccess.txt -> .htaccess
2. Enabled Mod_Rewrite on Apache2:`a2enmod rewrite` then `service apache2 restart`
3. Changed the apache2.conf file, located at /etc/apache2/ :
   Where is

`<Directory /var/www/your-store>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>`

You Change to

`<Directory /var/www/your-store>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>`

Answer (score 0):

First I don't think rewrite mod is enabled by default. enable it according to distro. for ubuntu - `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Try to change `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride All` in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yousiteFile`

Ubuntu and some distros work differently. second the default vhost has override set to none so that the htaccess is not allowed to rewrite anything.

restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `AllowOverride All` makes the SEO URL works for me.

As mentioned above, make sure to

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

to enable rewrite on Apache.

Then make sure the RewriteEngine On is added to the domains in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

Answer (score -2):

I have a solution for http 404 error. Even I faced a difficulties in starting but now it is very easy to solve it.

Login Opencart Admin .. then edit setting ..then in server section disable use SEO url. Then you will not get any error. Bye

Or if you don't want to disable url then follow below method.

Just edit `.htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess`.
You will get this file in root folder.